# Using XML2JSON dart package

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I am using XML2JSON dart package in Flutter to download weather and assign it to variables to display. The XML2JSON package will print out all the data, but the sky condition has nested data like below:

`<sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="4700"/>`

I just cannot find an example in the docs on how to get down to the nested data.  All the other fields are top level and easy to get to as below:

`<wind_speed_kt>4</wind_speed_kt>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!?

```
Future<dynamic> getData(String icaoIdent) async {
   try {
     http.Response response = await http.get(link + icaoIdent);
     parse(response.body);
     xml2json.parse(response.body);
     var jsondata = xml2json.toParker();
     var mydata = json.decode(jsondata);

     stationid = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["station_id"].toString();
     rawmetar = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["raw_text"].toString();
     obstime =
         mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["observation_time"].toString();
     temp = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["temp_c"].toString();
     windspeed =
         mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["wind_speed_kt"].toString();
     if (windspeed == '0') {
       windDS = 'Calm';
     } else {
       windDS = '$winddirection\u00B0' + ' @ ' + '$windspeed' + ' KTS';
     }
     dewpoint = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["dewpoint_c"].toString();
     winddirection =
         mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["wind_dir_degrees"].toString();
     elevation = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["elevation_m"].toString();

     visibility = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["visibility_statute_mi"]
         .toString();
     altimeter = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["altim_in_hg"].toString();

     fltcategory = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["flight_category"];

     //SkyCondition ______

     skycondition = mydata["response"]["data"]["METAR"]["sky_condition"];

     return mydata;
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml2json also translates using badgerfish and gdata as outputs IIRC gdata might allow access to these fields.